# Can't decode base64 encoded string

Tags: swift

I found this little `String` extension that allows me to decode a base64-encoded string in Swift:

```
extension String {

    func base64Decoded() -> String? {
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: self) else { return nil }
        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    }

}
```

However, when I make this call:

```
let toBeDecoded = "Rj4PbzLkUlkQr0XUYLWIcgwMa+GhiU1bY6BOn2A1Ea7pi1GSWzd3py73yPFe2CEr+HLBYc39iSbDqxvCetBQEw=="
let decodedSecret = toBeDecoded.base64Decoded()!
```

...my app falls over trying to unwrap a nil optional.

I have checked with a few online decoder tools. Some manage it, some don't. What could be the problem here? This is a secret to an API I'm using (deleted now, of course).

Comment: the encoded data is not utf8 : try to decode using .ascii

Comment: The data you're looking to decode appears to be valid base64-encoded data, but the _resulting_ data doesn't appear to be a UTF-8 string. Are you sure this secret was originally UTF-8 text?

Comment: Unfortunately the API that generated the key does not tell me the original format. I shall try ascii. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is two-fold.

The trivial part is that you are force-unwrapping an optional return type, which can easily be resolved by `if let` or nil coalescing.

The other part is that the encoded data is not actually a `.utf8` string.  It seems to be `.ascii`

If not knowing the actual string encoding is a problem you will regularly face, it might be worth extending the extension (!) to accommodate this.

```
extension String {
   func base64Decoded() -> (String, String.Encoding)? {
      let supportedEncoding: [String.Encoding] = [.ascii, .utf8, .utf16]  //etc.
      guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: self),
            let encoding = supportedEncoding.first(where: {String(data: data, encoding: $0) != nil})
      else {return nil}
      return (String(data: data, encoding: encoding)!, encoding)
   }
}
```

The method now also return the encoding type.  If this isn't useful, revert to just returning the optional `String`.

Unfortunately `String.Encoding` is a struct with many static values rather than an enum, which means it's necessary to define the various encodings values.  If it was an enum it would be simple to iterate over the `.allcases` values.

Comment: -1 because this doesn't address OP's use case. OP's data is neither UTF-8, _nor_ ASCII. UTF-8 is byte compatible with ASCII, so any ASCII string can, by definition, be decoded as UTF-8. You can check a tool like https://cryptii.com/pipes/base64-to-binary — the decoded string contains many bytes well out of the range of ASCII. (For those wondering why decoding with `.ascii` works: it's a lenient decoding process by default, and you get non-ASCII garbage data out.)

Comment: Ok I’m going to try it with ascii.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was missing. I am now able to decode the key. Thank you very much @flanker! I can work on improving the error handling.